# How to make a non interactive shell scripts

Tags: linux, bash, shell, scripting

I want to make a non-interactive shell script,where I can give options at the beginning of the execution of the script.

Where I can hard-code the various actions to be taken when different inputs are provided by user.

## for example:

Below should perform some action on `target.txt`

```
user@/root>myPlannedScript -p targer.txt
```

Below should perform some other actions on the `target.txt`

```
user@/root>myPlannedScript -a targer.txt
```

## For example:

`cat` tool performs various actions when different options are given. I want my script to act like this:

```
:/root> cat --h  
Usage: cat [OPTION] [FILE]...  
Concatenate FILE(s), or standard input, to standard output.  

  -A, --show-all           equivalent to -vET  
  -b, --number-nonblank    number nonblank output lines  
  -e                       equivalent to -vE  
  -E, --show-ends          display $ at end of each line  
  -n, --number             number all output lines  
  -r, --reversible         use \ to make the output reversible, implies -v  
  -s, --squeeze-blank      never more than one single blank line  
  -t                       equivalent to -vT  
  -T, --show-tabs          display TAB characters as ^I
```

Comment: What's you problem, exactly ?

Comment: I have a script where I have used user interaction (read tool)for providing target.txt, Now I want to execute this command in one go by providing the target.txt file name in a single line.

Comment: The canonical answer is at http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/035

Answer (score 0):

query.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
if [ $# -eq 0 ]
then echo do one thing
else echo do other thing
fi
```

"query.sh" => do one thing

"query.sh anythingYouPut" => do other thing ;oP

but if you really want a parameter for each action

```
#!/bin/bash
if [ -z "$1" ]
then
  echo do nothing
else
  if [ $1 -eq 1 ]
  then
    echo do one thing
  fi
  if [ $1 -eq 2 ]
  then
    echo do other thing
  fi
fi
```

"query.sh" => do nothing

"query.sh 1" => do one thing

"query.sh 2" => do other thing